# Spring Data JPA: @Query gives error java.sql.SQLException: Column 'id' not found

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa

I am trying to run the following query

```
@org.springframework.stereotype.Repository
public interface ReportingParamRepository extends Repository<ReportingParamDAO, Integer> {

    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT student, AVG(height) FROM ReportingParams GROUP BY student")
    public List<ReportingParamDAO> getAverageGroupByStudent();
}
```

This is the DAO

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ReportingParams")
@NamedQuery(name = "ReportingParams.findAll", query = "SELECT r FROM ReportingParamDAO r")
public class ReportingParamDAO extends BaseDAO<Integer, ReportingParam> implements DAO<Integer> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "student", nullable = true)
    private StudentDAO studentBean;

    @Column
    private Long height;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public StudentDAO getStudentBean() {
        return studentBean;
    }

    public void setStudentBean(StudentDAO studentBean) {
        this.studentBean = studentBean;
    }

    public Long getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(Long height) {
        this.height = height;
    }
}
```

But on executing the repository method I get the following error

```
java.sql.SQLException: Column 'id' not found.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:964) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar:5.1.43]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:897) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar:5.1.43]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:886) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar:5.1.43]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar:5.1.43]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.findColumn(ResultSetImpl.java:1077) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar:5.1.43]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getInt(ResultSetImpl.java:2567) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar:5.1.43]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingResultSet.getInt(DelegatingResultSet.java:283) ~[commons-dbcp2-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingResultSet.getInt(DelegatingResultSet.java:283) ~[commons-dbcp2-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.IntegerTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(IntegerTypeDescriptor.java:62) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:238) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:234) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:224) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:300) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.extractKeysFromResultSet(Loader.java:789) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:714) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:972) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:930) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2617) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2600) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2429) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2424) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
...
```

If I run the query directly from mysql terminal it works fine and I get the proper output. Can someone please help? Thanks !!

Comment: column name is UPPER CASE but the SQL invoked is lower case? And perhaps comment on why the SQL you say is being invoked has no such "id" in it, whereas the exception complains about it

Comment: maybe name of columns are it's case sensitive...

Comment: @NeilStockton  exactly NeilStockton

Comment: @NeilStockton Sorry but I didn't get it. Which column name is upper case? id, student and height all are lower case.

Comment: @JasonKrs Sorry but I didn't get it. id, student and height all are lower case

Comment: present the DDL of your table. present the actual SQL invoked (in the Hibernate log). The exception is about "id", so obviously that is the column we are referring to.

Comment: I think ALL columns names and cases should match in your beans an in the DDL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can't work. Your query fetches a student object, which you are trying to map to a list of ReportingParamDAO's.